# Pytorch: No training effect after deepcopy

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

I tried to make a copy of a neural network in pytorch and subsequently train the copied network, but training does not seem to change the weights in the network after copying. [This post](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/are-there-any-recommended-methods-to-clone-a-model/483/10) suggests that `deepcopy` is a convenient way to make a copy of a neural network, so I tried using that in my code.

The code below works just fine and shows that the weights and accuracy of the network are different after training from before training. However, when I toggle so that `network_cp=deepcopy(network)` and `optimizer_cp=deepcopy(optimizer)`, the accuracy and weights before and after training are exactly the same.

```
# torch settings
torch.backends.cudnn.enabled = True 
device = torch.device("cpu")

# training settings
learning_rate = 0.01
momentum = 0.5
batch_size_train = 64
batch_size_test = 1000

# get MNIST data set
train_loader, test_loader = load_mnist(batch_size_train=batch_size_train,
    batch_size_test=batch_size_test)

# make a network
network = Net()
optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=learning_rate,
    momentum=momentum)
network.to(device)

# train network
train(network, optimizer, train_loader, device)

# copy network
network_cp = network
#network_cp = deepcopy(network)
optimizer_cp = optimizer
#optimizer_cp = deepcopy(optimizer)

# get edge weights and accuracy of the copied network
acc1 = float(test(network_cp, optimizer_cp, test_loader, device))
weights1 = np.array(get_edge_weights(network_cp))

# train copied network
train(network_cp, optimizer_cp, train_loader, device)

# get edge weights and accuracy of the copied network after training
acc2 = float(test(network_cp, optimizer_cp, test_loader, device))
weights2 = np.array(get_edge_weights(network_cp))

# compare edge weights and accuracy of copied network before and after training
print('accuracy', acc1, acc2)
print('abs diff of weights for net1 and net2', np.sum(np.abs(weights1-weights2)))
```

To run the code above, include these imports and function definitions:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.nn as tnn
import torch.nn.functional as tnf
from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np

def load_mnist(batch_size_train = 64, batch_size_test = 1000):
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torchvision.datasets.MNIST('temp/', #'/data/users/alice/pytorch_training_files/',
                                   train=True, download=True,
                                   transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                                       torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                           (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                                       ])),
        batch_size=batch_size_train, shuffle=True)

    test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        torchvision.datasets.MNIST('temp/', #'/data/users/alice/pytorch_training_files/',
                                   train=False, download=True,
                                   transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                                       torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                       torchvision.transforms.Normalize(
                                           (0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                                     ])),
        batch_size=batch_size_test, shuffle=True)

    return(train_loader, test_loader)

def train(network, optimizer, train_loader, device, n_epochs=5):
    network.train()
    for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
        for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = network(data)
            loss = tnf.nll_loss(output, target)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

def test(network, optimizer, test_loader, device):
    network.eval()
    test_loss, correct = 0, 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = network(data)
            test_loss += tnf.nll_loss(output, target, size_average=False).item()
            pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
            correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).sum()
    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    print('\nTest set: Avg. loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {}/{} ({:.0f}%)\n'.format(
        test_loss, correct, len(test_loader.dataset),
        100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset)))

    return(float(correct)/float(len(test_loader.dataset)))

def get_edge_weights(network):
    layers = [module for module in network.modules()][1:]
    output = np.zeros(1)
    for j, layer in enumerate(layers):
        weights = list(layer.parameters())[0]
        weights_arr = weights.detach().numpy()
        weights_arr = weights_arr.flatten()
        output = np.concatenate((output,weights_arr))
    return output[1:]

class Net(tnn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 =tnn.Linear(784,264)
        self.fc2 = tnn.Linear(264,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = tnf.relu(self.fc1(x.view(-1,784)))
        x = tnf.relu(self.fc2(x))
        return tnf.log_softmax(x)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After `optimizer_cp = deepcopy(optimizer)`, the `optimizer_cp` still wants to optimize the old model's parameters (as defined by `optimizer = optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)`).

After deep copying the model, the optimizer needs to be told to optimize this new model's parameters:

`optimizer_cp = optim.SGD(network_cp.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, momentum=momentum)`

Comment: would this reset the parameters of optimizer? If so, how can I preserve them?